# Why wont my jQuery cycle.js slider autostart?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using the cycle.js app for jQuery but my slider wont auto start :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$('#slideshow').after('<div id="nav" class="nav">').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  3000,
    timeout: 0,
    auto:  'true',
    pager:  '#nav',
    pause: 1
});

});
```

Comment: should `'true'` be the boolean value `true`?

Comment: can you post the relevant html?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the javascript and html (but without the jQuery files and) http://jsfiddle.net/w5SkH/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set some duration in the `timeout` or else it will disable auto advance:

```
$('#slideshow').after('<div id="nav" class="nav">').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  3000,
    timeout: 3000,
    pager:  '#nav',
    pause: 1
})
```